# What is the difference between "vorgezogenen" and "früh"?

Tags: word-usage

When I read an article, I saw a word "vorgezogenen" which means early. I remember that "früh" means also early.

What is the difference between "vorgezogenen" and "früh"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Vorgezogen" means that something that was scheduled for a time now happens earlier. "Früh" just means that something happens early.

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop an understanding for the different meaning (or usage) of these words you need examples.

Here are sentences where "vorgezogen" und "früh" appear in a typical way:

> Als wir aufbrachen, war es noch sehr früh.
>
> Am frühen Nachmittag kamen die ersten Gäste.
>
> Am Sonntag finden vorgezogene Neuwahlen statt.
>
> Tagungsordnungspunkt 3 wird vorgezogen und findet somit früher statt, Tagungsordnungspunkt 2 wird dafür nach hinten verschoben und findet somit später statt.
>
> Früh übt sich, was ein Meister werden will. [Popular proverb]
>
> Vorgezogene Prüfungstermine erlauben es, die Ausbildung früher abzuschließen.

For a descriptive definition of the meaning of the two, see Retat's answer, which is satisfactory.

Or simply use a better pair of English expressions: früh --> early; vorgezogen --> preliminary

Answer (score 0):

**Vorgezogen** is the *Partizip II* of the verb *vorziehen*. Such participles can be used as adjectives and describe the result of the action applied to the noun then.

*Vorziehen* means *to pull to the front* and *to prefer*. So e.g.

> vorgezogene Wahlen

are elections that "have been pulled to the front", elections that would have taken place later by the regular order but held now because of circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

"Vorgezogen" means "pulled to the front of the timeline." That *implies* early (at least relative to other events).

"Early" explicitly means early.And in the "absolute," not relative sense.